# Set authentication request prop in j2me works?

Tags: authentication, mobile, java-me, midp

I have followed the answer to [HTTP authentication in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950885/http-authentication-in-j2me) by setting the request property for HttpConnection object with

> `setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ encodedUserAndPass)`

but it didn't work.

- When make request to **Http** protocol -> 401 Unauthorized
- When make request to **Https** protocol -> javax.microedition.pki.CertificateException: Certificate was issued by an unrecognized entity.

Has anyone have the problem solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you encoded "username:password" properly with base64?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have two separate problems

1. Make sure you have Base64 encoded the details
2. For ssl make sure the certificate you are using on the webserver is signed by an authority that there is an appropriate root certificate installed for on the device you are testing with.