# upload file from java application on mobile to web server

Tags: java, java-me

i would like to know if it is possible for me to upload say a text file on the web server of my webhost (000webhost.com) directly from my mobile phone java application. Actually i want this java application me and my college friends are developing to send a text file to the web server that would be plotted by this applet on the website. I somehow need to get the text file from java (mobile phone) to the webserver . Now the url the java application should access is net2ftp.com which asks for a few details like username, password, FTP server etc that should be auto entered by the java code (like these details are provided in the java script and it logins me in automatically) the next page after login is net2ftp.com/index.php which has an upload tab ...this tab should also be auto clicked by the java script and then it asks me to choose the file to upload and then click the upload button.....does any one has any idea if 
a) this approach is practical?
b) any scripts you have ever come across that could help in achieving this ?

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME) could help..

the sample is from Nokia, you can use this to upload a file to a http server,

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950885/http-authentication-in-j2me) might help regarding the authentication bit.